# Linking an html form to a php api based off of CodeIgniter framework?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, validation

So I am creating a web application for school which will have no ability to add users. It is a member-only site, so there is a login function that will check if the logged in user is a valid user within the database. I'm having trouble getting the html login form (login.html) to connect successfully with our API (login_controller.php). The main issue at the moment is that the link in form action brings up localhost/application/controllers/login_controller.php  (doesn't exist) instead of bringing up localhost/CMPS285_Team1/SGA connect/application/controllers/login_controller.php  Please help! Two files are below:

login.html---

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="databaseandverification" href="/application/controllers/login_controller.php"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/login/reset.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500,700,900|RobotoDraft:400,100,300,500,700,900'>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/login/login1.css">



</head>
<body>

    <div class="pen-title">
        <div style="text-align: center;"><img src="../images/finalsgaconnectlogo.png" alt="SGA Connect" width="" height=""></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Form Module-->
    <div class="module form-module">
        <h2><div style="text-align:center">Login</div></h2>
        <form action="/application/controllers/login_controller.php" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <!--<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" /> -->
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" maxlength="50" />
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" maxlength="32"/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

login_controller.php---

```
<?php
class Login_controller extends CI_Controller
{
    function validate(){
//       when posting  json data to the api
        $json = key($this->input->post(NULL, TRUE));
        $json = json_decode($json);
        $username = $json->username;
        $password = md5($json->password);
//        when posting with a normal post method with parameters
//        $username = $this->input->post('username');
//        $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $query = $this->membership_model->validate($username,$password);
        if($query) {
            $data['status'] = 'Logged in';
        }
        else{
            $data['status'] = 'not logged in ';
        }
        $this->load->view('verify', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call files that way. Form action need http request string such as:

```
<form action="http://localhost/project/index.php/login_controller/validate" method="post">
```

If you load url helper, you can call it in way:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('login_controller/validate'); ?>http://localhost/project/index.php/login_controller/validate" method="post">
```

Before that you would like to autoload url helper in `APPPATH . 'config/autoload.php'` file.

Also, if you don't include extension of viewfile (i.e. `$this->load->view('verify', $data);`), CodeIgniter will look for `verify.php` file in views directory. Otherwise, you have to mention extension, like:

```
$this->load->view('verify.html', $data);
```

But I am not sure if you would be able to read PHP variables in there. It is common practice to save all view files with php extension though.

If you are using CI version 3.0.x controller need to be capitalized `Login_controller.php`.